# jQuery datetimepicker does not support html5 validation

Tags: html, jquery, validation, jquerydatetimepicker

I have one date-time field in my form:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" required />

$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
   datepicker: true,
   timepicker: true,
   lang: 'pl'
});
```

Every field in my form has attribute required. When I tried submit form with unfulfilled required field, every field return html5 validation message, except datetimepicker.

Anyone can tell my, why jQuery datetimepicker does not support basic html5 validation? Is there some way to avoid this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Check this...

I have tested. The validation is working..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test HTML5 with Date Picker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

 <form action="#" method="post">
 <p>Name: <input type="text" id="name" required></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" required></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess that you tell about jQueryUI datepicket, but issue concerns jquery.datetimepicker.js library http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/